# ComboBox SelectedItem shows System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I insert data from my database to `combobox`, and now I want to display value of this `combobox` into `label`, but every time instead of getting value of `combobox`, I get `System.Data.DataRowView` in my `label`.

I use this code for connection, it works fine:

```
OracleConnectionStringBuilder sb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
sb.DataSource = "localhost";
sb.UserID = "library";
sb.Password = "library";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(sb.ToString());
conn.Open();
OracleDataAdapter TITLES = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT NAME FROM TITLE", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
TITLES.Fill(dt);
cmbBooks.DisplayMember = "NAME";
cmbBooks.DataSource = dt;
conn.Close();
```

And then I want to get `SelectedItem` using this code:

```
label1.Text = cmbBooks.Items[cmbBooks.SelectedIndex].ToString();
```

How to solve it?

Comment: If you populate your control with DataRowView items, and you select one, the selected item will be the one you selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`GetItemText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.dynamics.mobile.framework.controls.combobox.getitemtext.aspx) method:

```
label1.Text = cmbBooks.GetItemText(cmbBooks.SelectedItem);
```